# How to add a UIToolbar programmatically to an iOS app?

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

Can't seem to find a tutorial which does as the question title describes. I'd like to understand just where the UIToolbar needs to be declared and how to get it onto my view layer.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

`UIToolbar` is a subclass of `UIView`, so the short answer to your question is: just like any other view.

Specifically, this is an example of how to programmatically create a toolbar. The context in this snippet is `viewDidLoad` of a view controller.

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[items addObject:[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWith....] autorelease]];
[toolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
[items release];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[toolbar release];
```

See [UIToolbar](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [UIBarButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIBarButtonItem) documentation for details.

Comment: i like to have the button right at the center of tool bar, how can i do that?

Comment: @MicRO Probably have this figured out by now, but: `UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];`

Comment: Use the view controller's `navigationController` property if you can. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12313602/242933

Comment: better do this in viewDidLayoutSubviews since the size of UIToolbar differs for landscape mode.

Answer (score 79):

If you're using `UINavigationController` then the toolbar comes with it by default.

You can add it using following line of code:

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
```

And to add button to your Toolbar you can use following code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *item1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *item2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:nil];
```

`flexibleItem` is used to maintain proper distance between the two buttons that we have created above.

Now you can add these three items in order to make them visible on your view.

```
NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:item1, flexibleItem, item2, nil];   
self.toolbarItems = items;
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: I think this approach is better, since the height of the toolbar may change in the future.

Comment: There any easy way to animate this puppy? One of my VCs uses it, but the one underneath it does not. Switching is discontinuous.

Comment: I think this is a better answer.

Comment: To animate, use `[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES]`  Note that `self.navigationController.toolbar.items = items` does *not* work.  :-)

Comment: Should I set `toolbarItems` in `init` or `viewDidLoad`? We can do it in `init` since we don't need to access `view` to do it. But, iOS really shouldn't access `toolbarItems` until after `viewDidLoad`. If that's the case, then I'd rather defer and set `toolbarItems` in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: This also adds toolbar to all viewControllers of one NavigationController, anyway to add it only on the current VC?

Answer (score 11):

**iOS 11+ SWIFT 4 + Xcode 9 + Constraints**

*Works for both landscape + Portrait* 
[image]

[image: Portrait]

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height)//44 for iPhone x, 20 for other iPhones
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red


        let toolBar = UIToolbar()
        var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
        items.append(
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .save, target: nil, action: nil)
        )
        items.append(
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(tapsOnAdd))
        )
        toolBar.setItems(items, animated: true)
        toolBar.tintColor = .red
        view.addSubview(toolBar)

        toolBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let guide = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
            toolBar.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
            toolBar.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
            toolBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            toolBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true

        }
        else {
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: toolBar, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: toolBar, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
            NSLayoutConstraint(item: toolBar, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0).isActive = true

            toolBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44).isActive = true
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm not a big iOS pro. But adding view items in viewDidAppear seems wrong. If for example you present a view on top of it and then dismiss, viewDidAppear would get called and add another UIToolbar on top of it? :)

Comment: @HelloimDarius true!  However you can define as per your use case.

Comment: @Jack it does not work on rotation, constraint should be on `view` not `guide`

Comment: @GSerjo constraint must **respective of [safeAreaLayoutGuide](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2891102-safearealayoutguide)**, otherwise  **toolBar will overlaps with home-indicator**.

Comment: @Jack, as you can see in your second screenshot, the toolbar looks a bit weird, it' because constraints

Answer (score 3):

**To show the Toolbar at the bottom with space between two button on at Left Side , and another at Right side**

```
-(void)showToolBar
{
    CGRect frame, remain;
    CGRectDivide(self.view.bounds, &frame, &remain, 44, CGRectMaxYEdge);
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    UIBarButtonItem *button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Send" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *button2=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:nil];
    [toolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:button1,spacer,button2,nil]];
    [toolbar setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
}
```

**Note: To Give space between to Button we add line as below**

```
UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
```

**and add spacer to the**

```
[toolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:button1,spacer,button2,nil]];
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how you implement a `UIToolbar` in your app.

```
// declare frame of uitoolbar 
UIToolBar *lotoolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 170, 320, 30)];
[lotoolbar setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

UIBarButtonItem *button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"DATE" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dateToolbardoneButtonAction)];

UIBarButtonItem *button2=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"TIME" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(timeToolbarbuttonAction)];

[lotoolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:button1, nil];
[lotoolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:button2, nil];
[mainUIview addSubview:lotoolbar];
```

You should also have to implement the following delegate methods:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
}
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
    NSLog(@"textViewDidChange:");
}

- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView{
    NSLog(@"textViewDidChangeSelection:");
}

- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    [lotextview setText:@""];
    NSLog(@"textViewShouldBeginEditing:");
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this simple Method:**

```
    UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 44);
    UIBarButtonItem *button1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Send" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(sendAction)];

    UIBarButtonItem *button2=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(cancelAction)];

    [toolbar setItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:button1,button2, nil]];
    [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5:**

Result:
[image]

**Code:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    
    self.navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false
    
    let toolBarItems = ["Tab1","Tab2"]
    segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: toolBarItems)
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

    let space = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
    let cameraBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .camera, target: self, action: nil)
    let segmentedControlBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: segmentedControl)
    let addBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addAction))
    self.toolbarItems = [cameraBarButtonItem, space, segmentedControlBarButtonItem, space, addBarButtonItem]
    
}

@objc func addAction() {
    print("Add")
}
```